# Position one div over another div with a certain length

Tags: html, css

I'm looking to achieve the following layout:

I have to images which should be next to each other at the top.
Then I want a straight white line going from the left picture (x-coordinate) and nearly the top (y-coordinate) to nearly the bottom.

I have come so far in my design but when I change the window size it changes aswell: https://jsfiddle.net/toekttbu/

```
HTML:

<div class="container">
  <img src="https://pixabay.com/static/uploads/photo/2013/09/17/20/22/seagull-183229_960_720.jpg" id="pic-1">

   <img src="https://pixabay.com/static/uploads/photo/2015/10/29/14/44/sunset-1012477_960_720.jpg" id="pic-2">

   <div id="white-line>
   </div>
</div>

CSS:

body {
  background-color: #000;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.container {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

#pic-1 {
  position: absolute;
  width: 35.35%;
  background-color: #f00;
}

#pic-2 {
  width: 64.65%;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
}

#white-line {
  width: 5px;
  position: absolute;
  height: 350%;
  background-color: #FFF;
  top: 100%;
  left: 7%;
}
```

I want the white line always to stay on the same position on the seagull. I know why it is not working, because the white line is being position using the 100px from the height of the container.

I would need to position it using a percentage of the height of the seagull. Is this possible using CSS only?

Also I want the white line always to be as long as the text which will be under the pictures. So it might have a different length across different pages. Is this also possible using CSS ?

Thanks very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

**Edit:** if you want the line higher and a bit longer than the text, you need to change some values, for example:

```css
#pic-1,
#pic-2 {
  margin-top: -5%
}

p {
  padding: 20% 5% 20px 5%;
  margin-top: 5%;
}
```

**DEMO**

```css
body {
  background-color: #000;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  color: #fff;
}

.container {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

#pic-1 {
  position: absolute;
  width: 35.35%;
  background-color: #f00;
  margin-top: -15%;
}

#pic-2 {
  width: 64.65%;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  margin-top: -15%;
}

p {
  position: relative;
  padding: 10% 5% 0px 5%;
  margin-top: 15%;
  margin-left: 15px;
}

p:before {
  content: "";
  width: 5px;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #fff;
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  margin-left: -15px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img src="https://pixabay.com/static/uploads/photo/2013/09/17/20/22/seagull-183229_960_720.jpg" id="pic-1">
  <img src="https://pixabay.com/static/uploads/photo/2015/10/29/14/44/sunset-1012477_960_720.jpg" id="pic-2">
  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut euismod, nibh et vestibulum lobortis, erat mauris tempor tellus, ac condimentum massa tortor a ante. Ut ut eleifend purus. Quisque semper neque vulputate libero eleifend, a tincidunt diam aliquet.
    Proin vehicula, erat id hendrerit suscipit, ante justo iaculis mauris, a ullamcorper ipsum ligula eget sapien. Nulla lorem leo, ullamcorper at justo dapibus, bibendum maximus metus. Aliquam tempus ligula rhoncus, rutrum magna a, dictum nibh. Fusce
    accumsan neque egestas nibh lacinia tristique.
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes that looks like it! I have tried it out but I still struggle with something. What if I want the white line on the side a bit higher than it is at the moment? When I change the height to e.g. 120% than it looses the behaviour that it stays at the same position with different screen sizes. Also is it possible that the line is a bit longer than the text and also stays like this when changing the browser window? Thanks a lot!!

Comment: Check edited answer. This will help you out I think.

Comment: Awesome. Totally helped me out. Thanks very much

Answer (score 0):

if the line will be always at the left side and start from 100px from top, why not using fixed position;

```
#white-line {
  width: 5px;
  position: fixed;
  height: 90%;//350% is 3.5 times the height of the parent. why ?
  background-color: #FFF;
  top: 100px;//is the picture always 100px tall ? play with the top position
  left: 30px;//no need to do with % because it should be at the same LEFT position
}
```

this is what I understand from the question, if I am wrong u can tell...

read about positioning: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_position.asp

Comment: Thanks very much! The answer from @NiZa is the one which fits to my question more